# How to change field into SSN format (###-##-####) in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I know how to edit a field to remove the dashes but how do I take a field that is a text field with 9 numbers and manipulate it so that it follows standard SSN formatting?  Open to VBA or Query (SQL) methods.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps use textbox InputMask property. It won't actually changing the existing data but should display with the dashes. Changing the data will likely involve string manipulation functions in VBA procedure to breakup the string and then reassemble with dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `Format(expression[, format[, firstdayofweek[, firstweekofyear]]])` function, which can show you your 9 symbols in desired format

```
?format("123456789","@@@-@@-@@@@")
123-45-6789
```

If you decided to change stored values you can use SQL query like this

```
UPDATE [tblTable] SET [ssn] = format([ssn],"@@@-@@-@@@@")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  One issue though is that this query doesn't preserve leading zeroes.  Is there a way to do so that you know of?